# How to read from Resource folder in a Cross Built Project

Tags: javascript, scala, jvm, scala.js, cross-build

I have a cross build project with the following structure:

```
<project root>
 +- jvm
 |   +- src/main/scala/main.Scala
 +- js
 |   +- src/main/scala/main.Scala
 +- shared
     +- src/main/scala/myLibrary.scala
     +- src/main/resources/myjsfile.js
```

Now in my js main.Scala file, I want to read in myjsfile.js.

I know in a standard Scala JVM project I can do the following:

```
  val is = getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("myjsfile.js")
  val str = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(is).mkString
```

Now my question is, how can I do this with my current folder structure?

If I run the following main.scala (js version):

```
package example

object Main extends App {
  
  val is = getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("")
  val str = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(is).mkString

  println(str)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSRun$ClosedException: Termination was requested by user
[error]     at org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSRun$$anon$1.run(ExternalJSRun.scala:184)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last fooJS / Compile / run for the full output
[error] (fooJS / Compile / run) org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSRun$ClosedException: Termination was requested by user
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 25 Jun 2020, 10:56:05
[IJ]sbt:root>
```

How can I overcome this error?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does `myjsfile.js` need to be in the `shared` project? Does the `jvm` project need it?

Comment: Maybe I am doing it wrong:

So I am creating a package for the JVM. In the shared folder I have all the main jvm code, with class definitions.

I want Scalajs to use these class definitions and run some tests. Scalajs will essentially just test the JSON output of some functions I wrote which reside in the shared folder.

I use scalajs for tests as it has a facade for a js library that has all the functionality I need.

Comment: from what you've said, I think `myjsfile.js` should be located in the `js` project's resource folder